# How to set Listview Itemtemplate when drag drop in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I have create simple drag drop in WPF. In my application there are two Listviews. I have to drag list items from first listview and drop the item to second listview. I have created custom data template for first listview. When i drag the first listview item into second listview the data template is not customized so items are not displayed. How to display the list items with generic. Please help. My Code is as below,

```
 <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox
            Name="memberCollection"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid
            Name="gridDrop"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="20,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ListBox.Drop="grid_Drop"
            ShowGridLines="True">

            <ListBox
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="10,10,0,0"
                AllowDrop="True" />           
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
ObservableCollection<Member> member = new ObservableCollection<Member>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            member.Add(new Member { Name = "Karthick", ID = "20011", Address = "10, MainRoad, Chennai" });            

            memberCollection.ItemsSource = member;
            DataContext = new Member();
        }

        private void memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            object selectedMember = memberCollection.SelectedItem as Member;
            if (selectedMember != null)
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(memberCollection, selectedMember, DragDropEffects.All);
        }

        private void grid_Drop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listContent = e.Source as ListBox;
            if (listContent != null)
                Console.WriteLine("", Grid.GetColumn(listContent), Grid.GetRow(listContent));

            DataObject item = (((DragEventArgs)e).Data) as DataObject;
            object Target = ((Grid)(sender)).DataContext;
            object listItem = item.GetData(Target.GetType());

            if (listItem != null)
            {
                //listContent.Items.Add(listItem.Name.ToString());
                //listContent.Items.Add(listItem.ID.ToString());
                //listContent.Items.Add(listItem.Address.ToString()); 

                //listContent.ItemTemplate = memberCollection.ItemTemplate;                              

                listContent.Items.Add(listItem);

            }
        }
```

[image: Current Output]

[image: I want to display like this]

Comment: @mm8, Thanks for your reply,. My requirement is listbox one only display name, when drag the listbox one, selected items are display to the second list box. When i use same Item template name only display to the second listbox.

Comment: I don't  understand. What exaclty do you want to display in the second ListBox?

Comment: @mm8, please refer the second screenshot

Comment: What about it? Where does "20011" and "10, ..." come from?

Comment: @mm8, i have initialized the observablecollection of member class in code behind, please refer.  member.Add(new Member { Name = "Karthick", ID = "20011", Address = "10, MainRoad, Chennai" });

Comment: If you want to display some other properties of the dropped Member in the second ListBox, you should define another ItemTemplate. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the `DataTemplate` as a reusable resource, you can use it in both `ListBoxes`:

```
<Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox
            Name="memberCollection"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}" />

    <Grid
            Name="gridDrop"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="20,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ListBox.Drop="grid_Drop"
            ShowGridLines="True">

        <ListBox
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="10,10,0,0"
                AllowDrop="True"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If you want to display some other properties of the dropped `Member` in the second `ListBox`, you should define another `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="10,10,0,0"
    AllowDrop="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Address}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```